# $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ is to knot theory as $U_q(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ is to $?$

Tags: knot-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, topological-quantum-field-theory, yang-baxter-equations

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebra over the complex numbers, e.g. $\mathfrak{sl}_n$.

Then every representation $\DeclareMathOperator\Rep{Rep}V\in \Rep U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ over its quantum group gives a knot invariant, due to Reshitikin–Turaev (see e.g. Theorem 4.1 of [Catalano - Quantum framed knot invariants](https://www.mat.uniroma1.it/mat_cms/materiali/2014-2015/pinzari-24601-Catalano.pdf)):
$$F_V\ :\ \left\{\text{links }\subseteq \ M^3\right\}\ \to\ \mathbf{Q}[q^{\pm 1}].$$
My **question** is: what about $U_q(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ — does it give an invariant of **surfaces** in **four-manifolds**
$$F_V\ :\ \left\{\text{toruses }\subseteq \ M^4\right\}\ \to\ \mathbf{Q}[q^{\pm 1}]?$$
Is it related to $4$d Chern–Simons theory the same way that $3$d Chern–Simons theory is related to ordinary knot theory?

---

To justify this question a little bit: the reason $F_V$ exists in the first case is that $\Rep U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ is a (ribbon) braided monoidal category, i.e. there is an invertible element $R\in U_q(\mathfrak{g})^{\otimes 2}$ satisfying the Yang–Baxter equation
$$R_{12}R_{13}R_{23}\ =\ R_{23}R_{13}R_{12}, \hspace{15mm}(R_{12}=R\otimes\mathrm{id},\text{ etc}.)$$
There is an analogue of this for $U_q(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$, called $R(z)$ (see [R-matrices, affine quantum groups and applications](https://imsc.uni-graz.at/baur/ESI2017/R-matrices.pdf)), satisfying the spectral Yang–Baxter equation
$$R_{12}(z)R_{13}(zw)R_{23}(w)\ =\ R_{23}(w)R_{13}(zw)R_{12}(z).$$
To justify the torus $T^2$ replacing knots $S^1$ — the affine Lie algebra $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ is approximately maps from $S^1$ into $\mathfrak{g}$, so it's plausible we should pick up another $S^1$ somewhere.

Comment: TeX note, since it also came up while editing [another question of yours](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445937/defining-extended-tqfts-with-point-line-surface-operators): $\text{Rep}U_q(\mathfrak g)$ `\text{Rep}U_q(\mathfrak g)` is, I think, usually regarded as the wrong spacing.  $\operatorname{Rep}U_q(\mathfrak g)$ `\operatorname{Rep}U_q(\mathfrak g)` spaces better, and I have edited accordingly.  (If you're going to `Rep` a lot, then you can `\DeclareMathOperator\Rep{Rep}` at the beginning and then `\Rep U_q(\mathfrak g)`, and actually that's what I've done.)

Comment: I was told that the physics paper to look at here is Gauge Theory and Integrability, I
 by Costello, Witten and Yamazaki. https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.09993